# Google Tag Manager Cross-Origin Request to an Api Blocked

Tags: cors, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to get some data from our API (**myapi.com**) to display in our frontend application (**www.myfrontend.com**).

On **myfrontend.com**'s gtm, I have a tag that request myapi.com for some data:

```
  var HttpClient = function() {
    this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
        var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
            anHttpRequest.open("GET", aUrl, true);
            anHttpRequest.send(null);
        }
    }
var theurl = 'https:\/\/myapi.com/data?id=1';
var client = new HttpClient();
client.get(theurl, function(response) {
    var response1 = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(response1.content);
});
```

I'm getting a CORS error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://myapi.com/data?id=1

I added the api to the access control origin header:

```
access-control-allow-origin https://myapi.com
```

I can see in the network, the request to the api is successful and I can see the data but it nevers gets to my console.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As I posted it, I found the answer.

```
access-control-allow-origin https://myfrontend.com
```

Needed the access control allow origin header on the api, not on the frontend app.